# WPF single Click CheckBox on writeprotected DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have found many, many sugestions quite close to my question, but they all seem to be 'dirty hacks'.

My program displays a List of orders. The user should be able to mark orders from that list, and then save that selection to be later informed when the order arrives.

The DataGrid is bound to a DataTable Object, and with the writing enabled DataGrid it is working as intended, except for 2 things:

1. The user has to click two times, once for selecting the row, and then a second time to switch the checkbox
2. The usr can edit other fields in the datagrid which is not intended. Furthermore he can add rows to the datagrid, which might bring me to agony city regarding the database.

My goal is that the felds in the Datagrid are NOT changeable with the exception of the checkbox cell. I dont care if the user has to click the checkbox, the cell or even just the row to trigger the change but the change should be done in a single click.

Can someone hint me on that, I have lost the capacity to rate and evaluate all the different aproaches I mentioned earlier.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Checkbox Column create a Template Colum with an Checkbox inside. Then bind the Checkbox.IsChecked to your bound value. You can also set some Columns read only. In Code you only must set an Itemssource for your Datagrid.

Heres some XAML

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Row1" Binding="{Binding r1Value}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="CB" IsReadOnly="False">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding PropertyIsChecked}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: @Lorgarn - You can also use `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`.